# Event listener in vscode api for hyperlink in webview

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, event-handling, vscode-extensions

I am pretty new to VSCode extension development, for my extension i need to listen to hyperlink click on vscode.WebviewPanel and after that i need to change the default behavior of the hyperlink click action. So Is there any event listener in vscode api to fire when hyperlink is click on a webview?

Answer (score 0):

Webviews are just like webpages embedded in the editor. You can register a click handler in your webview script that intercepts clicks the same way you can in a normal webpage:

```
// In your webview script
const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let node = event && event.target;
    while (node) {
        if (node.tagName && node.tagName === 'A' && node.href) {
            // Handle click here by posting data back to VS Code
            // for your extension to handle
            vscode.postMessage({ ... });
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: preventDefault() doesn't work for me in VSCode 1.57

An external browser is opened with the link.

Adding `node.href = "#";` solved it.